# User connecting to Azure from On-Premise

Tags: azure

Current Infrastructure Setup:

1. Site-to-Site connectivity between On premise and Azure using the Secured VPN Tunnel.
2. Implementing Azure ADFS for AD Solution.
3. Data accumulated on a specific location on on-premise which will be pushed to ADLS using ADF.
4. PowerBI reporting on top of ADLS.

Question:

Trying to understand on the user perspective, if the user is at On Premise location and trying to access the Data Lake and PowerBI report, how does the connection happens?

It is like this: users traffic from on-premise goes through VPN tunnel, then hits the Azure Gateway and it is forwarded to Data Lake and Power BI report is generated and the response travels back again in the same path.

If so then a question comes on scalability of the tunnel.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

If the power BI got a external endpoint facing internet, All traffic from user will go through internet.

If your network team has added a rule if all the traffic has to go via VPN then it uses VPN tunnel.

"3. Data accumulated on a specific location on on-premise which will be pushed to ADLS using ADF." - It will uses the VPN tunnel for sure but for the user it may be via internet

Comment: so it means using the same tunnel data will be transferred, users will be connecting, users will be sending request and get back response using this same very tunnel. How do i think about scalablity option here. Something like - can we use multiple tunnels like: Couple of for data transfer, one for user connections (like authentication/authorization), couple of for user queries .. summing to 5 tunnel supporting one single S2S connection. If so, will this be cost effective solution?

Comment: Is the Power BI is exposed to Internet, If yes then you cannot use the tunnel. I would request you to review with your Networking team. The S2S is applicable if you are exposing the endpoint only to the Virtual network